# 'eine solche Arbeit' vs 'solch eine Arbeit'

Tags: word-usage

This is in my dictionary.

Why is it 'solche' in one case while 'solch' in the other case?

As far as I know, 'solch' is the indefinite form, right?

Answer (score 5):

**Solch** is a tricky word because it's a demonstrative pronoun but may be used as it was an adjective also. (In the past, all demonstrative pronouns had this feature but it died out for all but *solcher, solche, solches*.)

> Solch (eine) Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!
>
> So eine Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!

*Such (a) work I will never do again!*

> Diese Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!

*That work I will never do again!*

Clearly a demonstrative pronoun here. You are pointing a finger at the *Arbeit*.

---

> Eine solche Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!

*Such a work I will never do again!*

Ugh. The English translation is just the same. What's missing is the demonstrative mode. The pointing finger. *Solch* is hidden as it was an adjective. You can **also** translate it as

*A work of that kind I will never do again!*

> Eine solche schwere Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!

*A hard work of that kind I will never do again!*

Here *solche* is used as an adjective qualifying this particular *Arbeit* as something mentioned in a previous sentence.

---

To make it even more complicated, you can use *solch* (and the more common *so*) to point a finger to an adjective alone.

> Eine solch schwere Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!
>
> Eine so schwere Arbeit mache ich nie wieder!

*A **such hard** work I will never do again!*

Answer (score 1):

Keine historische, eher ein pragmatische Erklärung:

a) 'Solch' kommt in altertümlichen Ausdrucksweisen vor, zum Beispiel in alten Theaterstücken.

> Er soll kein solch Gewese machen!
>
> Solch Trachten ist mir fremd!

Man könnte in diesen Fällen aber auch, ohne einen Fehler zu machen, sagen:

> Er soll kein solches Gewese machen!
>
> Solches Trachten ist mir fremd!

Allerdings geht dabei die Kraft des Ausdrucks verloren.

b) In der heutigen Alltagssprache kommt 'solch' vor, wenn es dem Satz voransteht:

> Solch ein Missgeschick!
>
> Solch ein blauer Himmel!
>
> Solch ein schönes Wetter!
>
> Solch schönes Wetter!
>
> (NICHT: Solches schönes Wetter! [Versteht man, klingt aber falsch.])
>
> Solch einen Unsinn habe ich schon lange nicht mehr gehört!

c) *Voranstehend* finden wir es auch innerhalb von Sätzen wie:

> Ich habe **solch einen Hunger**!
>
> (NICHT: Ich habe einen solch Hunger. AUCH NICHT: Ich habe solchen einen Hunger.)
>
> Ich möchte gerne **solch ein Käsebrot**. [Sprecher zeigt auf das Brot.]
>
> Der Egon hat **solch einen Aufstand** beim Chef gemacht, dem klingeln noch jetzt die Ohren.
>
> (AUCH KORREKT: Der Egon hat **einen solchen Aufstand** beim Chef gemacht, dem klingeln noch jetzt die Ohren.)
>
> Mit **solch einem Unsinn** brauchst du mir gar nicht erst zu kommen!
>
> (AUCH KORREKT: Mit **einem solchen Unsinn** brauchst du  mir gar nicht erst zu kommen!)